# Change background color Bar Item xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to change the background of the Bar Item when it's selected but I'm not able to do it. At the moment I have only changed the color of the image (it's a white image and when it's selected it shows a yellow color) but I would like to change the background color.

Is it possible if my image is a .png without background?

To change the color of the image I use: selectedImageTintColor, which one I have to use in order to change the background?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide a code ? , also I don't get what do you want:-/ background of what ? what bar ?

Comment: I would like to change the background of my bar item when I select an item. It's a "TabBar".

Comment: Please show me how is the bar item initialized

Comment: I don't have a code Roma-MT, it's only created in the Storyboard. It's a TarBar with 5 different relationships.

Comment: Oh , I thought it is your custom view , sorry however I never experienced to work with a `storyboard` I can't help you :(

Comment: but I would try something like `[barItem setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about using storyboards, but you can do this programmatically. In your viewDidLoad,

```
UITabBarItem *item = [[self.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:someIndex];
[item setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
```

Of course, you will need to add your UITabBar as a property in your view controller and specify the index of the item you would like to add this to.